# Infectious ghouls, Astalor and the precise death sequence

Tags: hearthstone

I used [Twilight’Call](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Twilight%27s_Call) to summon two [infectious ghouls](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Infectious_Ghoul). As per the card, each was a 1/1. They were the only minions on board and the opponent killed them with the Flamebringer evolution of [Astalor](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Astalor_Bloodsworn).

On the board, they clearly died one after the other, so I expected the “long lived” one to get his brother’s effect and summon a ghoul. This did not happen, however. Is this a bug, or is there some advanced mechanic, whereby their death counts as simultaneous?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your explanation correctly, then there is not an advanced mechanic.

If both died due to the same effect/spell/etc (Blizzard and Consecrate would be similar triggers). Then they would both be dying at the same time and there would be no "body" left for the effect to transfer to. While the animation may show them dying from left to right they are dying simultaneously.

Comment: Very interesting! Has there been a change from back when cthun was introduced? Back then, subsequent cthun damages would spawn subsequent grim patrons, implying that the individual damages were not technically contemporaneous!

Comment: No change but "on damage" effects happen immediately mid-action while deathrattle effects happen at the end of the action.

Comment: @Ludi, there is a player-made [advanced rulebook](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Advanced_rulebook) that goes into details about how things like this work.